# How to send JSON Format HTTP Request to Server?

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-json

I am trying to send a HTTP Server request (JSON Encoded String) to server, but don't understand how to make the server request.

This is the format which gives me JSON response.

```
   {
"api_id": "Ddbl77c22oCVrXQs2WiZ",
"api_secret": "qjN9eEB9VVVKZm0PzKfqjN9eEB8",
"api_request": "login_user",
"data": {
    "user_name": "sampanchal2611@gmail.com",
    "user_type": "general",
    "password": "123456789",
    "device_id": "webdevdeid",
    "device_type": "test"
}
```

}

Comment: Dude, you just posted wayyy to much data that could compromise the security of your application. It appears your api uses oAuth. Dude, your api secret is called that for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data object (model) that will represent the data you want to send in your JSON.

Then use a library like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to send your data to the server.

Comment: That's a better answer then mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a http post to the url that the website accepts api requests from. Read the documentation of your api for more information.